# Problems with Interface Orientation and UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

Quick problem:

I have an UITabBarController with 2 navigation controllers [lets call them Left and Right Controller]

On the default selected Left Controller I can push a new View Controller that detects interface orientation.

On the Right Controller I can push the same View Controller but it won't detect interface orientation, or for that matter, It won't even go into the shouldAutoRotateInterface method at all T___T

Haaalp!!

If it is of any relevance, the View Contoller that I'm pushing use the hidesBottomBarWhenPushed property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does your uitabbarcontroller implement the auto rotate? any child viewcontroller that wants to implement autorotate has to have its parent implement autorotate.

Comment: Could yo tell me where can I set this property?
The project was created with the TAB BAR template, so the tabBarController is on the mainwindow.xib as an IBOutlet of the Appdelegate.

The weird thing is.... the controller on the left works ok.. it autorotates... but the one on the right doesn't T___T

Answer (score 13):

Most likely this is your problem:

> Tab bar controllers support a portrait
>   orientation by default and do not
>   rotate to a landscape orientation
>   **unless all of the root view controllers support such an orientation**.
>   When a device orientation
>   change occurs, the tab bar controller
>   queries its array of view controllers.
>   If any one of them does not support
>   the orientation, the tab bar
>   controller does not change its
>   orientation.

The solution is to override the following method on every view controller leading to your view:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    return YES;
}
```

For example, instead using the default `UITabBarController` in IB, replace it with your own subclass containing just the method above.

Comment: +1, although in my experience one need not subclass the UITabBarController. (At least, this is the case as of iOS SDK 4+; I'm not sure about previous versions.)

Comment: its amazing how everything is there in the documentation but we seldom bother to actually read it. Thanks Jano for the excerpt, it saved me from a lot of heartache.

Answer (score 8):

I'm a bit late to the party on this, but I ran into a problem with autorotation at startup for a tab bar app I wanted always to run in portrait.

The app's plist has the necessary settings to both start in and only allow portrait mode, and all my view controllers only allow portrait mode. Yet, when I started the app holding my iPhone in landscape, the app started in portrait, but then rotated to landscape!

Rather than subclass `UITabBarController`, I simply overrode `UITabBarController`'s `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method using a category on class `UITabBarController`. I included this code in my app delegate:

```
@implementation UITabBarController(UITabBarControllerCategory)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
                 (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Works beautifully, and is quite lightweight.

Comment: I have just read a big thread on SO that says it is not advisable to override methods of a class in a category of the class. It may work but pedantically speaking is not good design. Because, in effect what you have done here is replace the original implementation of UITabBarController class' shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation with your implementation. As opposed to subclasses which override superclass' method implementation and can invoke [super method], categories with same method names as in original class replace original method implementations.

Comment: Generally I agree with you. But, in the example I cited I _did_ want to replace the original class implementation, everywhere. This was the most streamlined way to do it, rather then subclassing `UITabBarController`. Had I subclassed `UITabBarController` my implementation of `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` would not have called the super-class method anyway. So, the extra overhead of subclassing would not have been worth the effort, best practices not withstanding. Sometimes you have to make tradeoffs for efficiency and time that are not always considered "best practices". :-)